# better approach regex than this

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am limiting my input to only accept this characters:

- apostrophe **'**
- open  parenthesis **(**
- close parenthesis **)**
- comma **,**
- hyphen **-**
- period **.**
- alphanumeric **A-Z a-z 0-9**
- space

I come up with this regex:

```
/^['(),-.A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/
```

Do I violate any regularization order in here? I just want to have the order of regex based on order I stated on the bullets above.

Comment: Use `/^['(),-.\w\s]+$/` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tweaking the regex in the question comment by @Mark Linus:

`/^[-'(),.\w\s]+$/`  *(moving the hyphen to the beginning of the character class)*

The reason: In a regex character class, `-` Specifies a range of characters, unless it's the first or the last character.

`,-.` means any characters from `,` to `.` inclusive. As it happens, `-` is the single character between those two (based on ASCII value), so it works out the same in this case. But it's probably not a good idea to put a hyphen anywhere in a character class except the beginning or the end unless you mean for it to specify a range.

Answer (score 0):

There's no really such thing as regular order for values, as far as I know. Just make something up for yourself and keep it consistent for all your expressions. Just use whatever feels comfortable.